# Why does Farm Simulator crash with GPU "3D-Engine" operating at full capacity?

Tags: gpu, gaming, task-manager

My Question sounds odd at first, but I then tried running a DIFFERENT game (Asphalt 9) on a DIFFERENT PC (Intel NUC) and the "3D" graph at the GPU section in TaskManager spikes at 100% as well, but the game does not crash.

My suspicion is, that if the "3D" section is at 100% usage, you still can't predict wheter a game is going to crash or not. Does it depend on "the GHz of the shader cores" or something like that?

GPU Model of "bad PC": GTX750 (or GT750, does that exist at all?)

Integrated CPU of "good PC": i5-8259U (I thought this was worse, because it's integrated, but seems to be a newer model...)

Comment: The crashes and GPU core usage are likely unrelated. The 750 is old, underpowered, may have parts that are aging and falling slightly out of spec, and running a game that is very demanding. The newer chip may simply be better optimised and use less power for the same effect, have less wear and tear and so on. GPU Usage is never an indication of whether something might crash, it is simply indicating how heavily used said device is.

Comment: I suspect the crashes likely have to do with the hardware not supporting the required version of (OpenGL and/or Vulkan) and DirectX. Cursoratory look indicates that the Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655 is more modern then the more than a decade old Nvidia card.